# Get All AD Groups That Have Blank Managed By Field

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes, where-object

I'm trying to get all AD groups that have a blank Managed By Name and the description of the AD group. I'm currently having issues with displaying no results using my filter, but am not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * | Where-Object {$_.ManagedBy -eq ""} | Select-Object manager,description | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\User\Desktop\AllNullManagedBy.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The current script is not showing any users which it should be showing several users

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Get-ADGroup` does not return an object with the `ManagedBy` attribute by default, you need to ask for it (`-Properties ManagedBy`):

```bash
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy, Manager, Description |
    Where-Object {-not $_.ManagedBy } | Select-Object samAccountName, Manager, Description |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\User\Desktop\AllNullManagedBy.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However, this operation is quite inefficient, you can use [LDAP filtering capabilities](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) for this:

```bash
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(!managedby=*)" -Properties Manager, Description |
    Select-Object samAccountName, Manager, Description |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\User\Desktop\AllNullManagedBy.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

As a side note, `Where-Object { $_.ManagedBy -eq "" }` is likely to not return any results, you would be querying for AD Groups where their `ManagedBy` attribute **is set** and it's value is equal to an **emptry string** instead of filtering for groups that **don't have the attribute set** or it's value is **`$null` or empty string** (`{-not $_.ManagedBy }`):

```bash
$null -eq '' # => False: comparison fails here
-not $null   # => True
-not ''      # => True
```